# Polymer event listener in ES6

Tags: javascript, polymer, ecmascript-6, babeljs, polymer-1.0

I'm using Polymer 1.0 with EcmaScript 6 and transpiling using Babel and Vulcanize.

I fire an event from a button, but I can't listen to it from my modal.

When I add an eventListner in the console, I can catch the event. But I can't from the modal.

I've tried to pass the listener as string and as the actual function, but it didn't work.

```
class MyEditButton {
    beforeRegister(){
        this.is= 'my-edit-button';
        this.extends = 'button';

        this.properties = {
            myObjectId: {
                type: Number,
                value: -1,
            }
        }
        this.listeners = {
            'tap': 'taphandler'
        }
    }
    taphandler(){
        this.fire(
            'my-edit-button-clicked',
            {'my-object-id': this.myObjectId}
        )
    }
}

Polymer(MyEditButton);
```

This is the modal that was supposed to listen to the event.

```
class MyModal {
    beforeRegister(){
        this.is = 'my-modal';

        this.listeners = {
            'my-edit-button-clicked': '_onButtonClick'
        };
    }

    _onButtonClick(e, details){
       console.log("Clicked!");
    }
}

Polymer(MyModal);
```

Does anybody knows why? Is there an "event scope" or it fires the event in just one direction?

Comment: Maybe it's an issue of how you place your elements in HTML? Please show your markup with the modal and edit button elements

Answer (score 1):

If your button were a child of the modal, the event would bubble up to the modal, and your existing code would work:

```js
HTMLImports.whenReady(_ => {
  "use strict";

  class MyEditButton {
    beforeRegister() {
      this.is = 'my-edit-button';
      this.extends = 'button';

      this.properties = {
        myObjectId: {
          type: Number,
          value: -1,
        }
      }
      this.listeners = {
        'tap': 'taphandler'
      }
    }
    taphandler() {
      this.fire(
        'my-edit-button-clicked', {
          'my-object-id': this.myObjectId
        }
      )
    }
  }

  Polymer(MyEditButton);

  class MyModal {
    beforeRegister() {
      this.is = 'my-modal';

      this.listeners = {
        'my-edit-button-clicked': '_onButtonClick'
      };
    }

    _onButtonClick(e, details) {
      console.log("Clicked!");
    }
  }

  Polymer(MyModal);
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.5.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
</head>
<body>
  <my-modal></my-modal>

  <dom-module id="my-modal">
    <template>
      <h1>My Pseudo Modal Dialog</h1>
      <button id="myButton" is="my-edit-button">Click</button>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/JKWNKB?editors=1011)

Otherwise if the button were a sibling, the event would bubble up to the document, skipping the modal. In this case, you would have to specify the target node as the modal when you call [`fire()`](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/api/Polymer.Base#method-fire) from the button:

```
 this.fire(
    'my-edit-button-clicked',
    { 'my-object-id': this.myObjectId },
    { node: document.querySelector('my-modal') } // direct signal at first my-modal node
  );
```

```js
HTMLImports.whenReady(_ => {
  "use strict";

  class MyEditButton {
    beforeRegister() {
      this.is = 'my-edit-button';
      this.extends = 'button';

      this.properties = {
        myObjectId: {
          type: Number,
          value: -1,
        }
      }
      this.listeners = {
        'tap': 'taphandler'
      }
    }
    taphandler() {
      this.fire(
        'my-edit-button-clicked',
        { 'my-object-id': this.myObjectId },
        { node: document.querySelector('my-modal') } // direct signal at first my-modal node
      );
    }
  }

  Polymer(MyEditButton);

  class MyModal {
    beforeRegister() {
      this.is = 'my-modal';

      this.listeners = {
        'my-edit-button-clicked': '_onButtonClick'
      };
    }

    _onButtonClick(e, details) {
      console.log("Clicked!");
    }
  }

  Polymer(MyModal);
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.5.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
</head>
<body>
  <my-modal></my-modal>
  <button id="myButton" is="my-edit-button">Click</button>

  <dom-module id="my-modal">
    <template>
      <h1>My Pseudo Modal Dialog</h1>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/vKxmKM?editors=1011)

<sup>*I'm confused how the button would be accessible if the dialog were truly modal, but let's assume the user can get to the button anyway...*</sup>

From Polymer [docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/instance-methods#instance-methods):

> `fire(type, [detail], [options]).` Fires a custom event. The `options` object can contain the following properties:
>
> - `node`. Node to fire the event on (defaults to `this`).
> - `bubbles`. Whether the event should bubble. Defaults to `true`.
> - `cancelable`. Whether the event can be canceled with `preventDefault`. Defaults to `false`.